# mergesort algorithm merge function doesnt work

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am trying to make my own version of mergesort, however, I am kind of stuck on how to merge two array back into a single array with a sequenced order.

Below is my code, after I try to run the programme, some number that does not make sense to me pop up, like `776247896 327641 57752310`.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong with my code? Please enlighten me. Thank you very much.

```
//nL is the length of left[]
//nR is the length of right[]
//nA is the length of A[]

void merge(int left[], int nL, int right[], int nR, int A[], int nA) {
    int temp[nA];
    
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    
    while (i < nL && j < nR) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            temp[k++] = left[i++];
        }
        else if (left[i] > right[j]) {
            temp[k++] = right[j++];
        }
    }
    
    while (i == nL && j < nR && k < nA) {
        temp[k++] = right[j++];
    }
    while (j == nR && i < nL && k < nA) {
        temp[k++] = left[i++];
    }
    
    for (int m = 0; m < nA; m++) {
        temp[m] = A[m];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int left[4] = { 13, 22, 25, 60};
    int right[4] = { 9, 11, 27, 55};
    int sorted[8];
    
    merge(left, 4, right, 4, sorted, 8);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", sorted[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: temp[m] = A[m];
Reverse this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final loop in the `merge` function does not copy from `temp` back to `A`, but the other way around.  It should be changed to:

```c
    for (int m = 0; m < nA; m++) {
        A[m] = temp[m];
    }
```

Note also these remarks:

- the length of the destination array should be the sum of the lengths of the left and right arrays, no need to specify it.
- the test `else if (left[i] > right[j])` is redundant, it should be removed.
- the test `while (i == nL && j < nR && k < nA)` is also redundant: at the end of the first loop, either `i == nL` or `j == nR` or both. You could simply write `while (j < nR)` and the following loop can be simplified too.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//nL is the length of left[]
//nR is the length of right[]
//nA is the length of A[]

void merge(int left[], int nL, int right[], int nR, int A[]) {
    int temp[nL + nR];
    
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    
    while (i < nL && j < nR) {
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            temp[k++] = left[i++];
        } else {
            temp[k++] = right[j++];
        }
    }
    
    while (i < nL) {
        temp[k++] = left[i++];
    }
    while (j < nR) {
        temp[k++] = right[j++];
    }
    
    for (int m = 0; m < k; m++) {
        A[m] = temp[m];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int left[4] = { 13, 22, 25, 60};
    int right[4] = { 9, 11, 27, 55};
    int sorted[8];
    
    merge(left, 4, right, 4, sorted);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", sorted[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

shouldnt it be reversed?

```
   temp[m] = A[m];
```

Hence your array A is full of random bytes stored on the stack.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really. Everything is fixed now.